# Python MySQLCannot Update With Dataset Containing 25k Records

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, execute, executemany

Important Details:

- mysql-connector-python==8.0.18
- I am using pypy3, which works as an alternate implementation of Python3
- Each item in the bulk_data list is a dict object with two items, each key is less than 10 characters and each value is no more than 40 characters.

Currently, I have a recordset of around 25k records, containing two pieces of data. I am attempting to update rows in my database with this information, but no matter what I try I receive "Use multi=True when executing multiple statements" as the error.

The oddities are as follows:
1. I have tries this as a bulk dataset using [executemany](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html)(sql, data_set). This cannot use "multi=True"
2. I have broken this down to single updates and use execute(sql, multi=True)

I have provided an example of the code using "executemany" below, assume bulk_data is a small version of what my data set looks like:

```
  bulk_data = [{'item_1':"TEST", 'item_2':"TEST2"}, {'item_1':"TEST3", 'item_2':"TEST4"}]
  self.setup_mysql_con()
  cursor = self._mysql.cursor()

  update_sql = """
  UPDATE `db_name`.`db_table`
  SET `column_1` = %(item_1)s
  WHERE `column_2` = %(item_2)s;
  """
  try:
    cursor.executemany(update_sql, bulk_data)
    self._mysql.commit()
  except Exception as es:
    self.print(str(es))
    self.print('[{}] Error updating records in DB.'.format(
    time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime())))
    pass

  cursor.close()
  self.close_mysql()
```

I am keeping the above because it is an example of code that -should- work and I am able to revert back if needed. Below is how the process is currently set up to work.

```
group_count = 1000
loop_num = 1
count = 0

total = len(data_list)

if total > 0:
  self.setup_mysql_con()
  cursor = self._mysql.cursor(buffered=True)

  while count < total:
    sub_data = data_list[(loop_num - 1) * group_count: loop_num * group_count]
    count = count + len(sub_data)
    update_sql = ""

    for data in sub_data:
      update_sql = update_sql + "UPDATE `db_name`.`db_table` SET `column` = '{}'
      WHERE `column_2` = '{}';\n".format(
                                         data['column_data'],
                                         data['column2_data']
                                         )

    loop_num = loop_num + 1

    try:
      for result in cursor.execute(update_sql, multi=True):
        if result.with_rows:
          self.fprint("Rows produced by statement '{}':".format(result.statement))
        else:
          self.fprint("Number of rows affected by statement '{}': {}".format(result.statement, result.rowcount))
      self._mysql.commit()
    except Exception as es:
      self.fprint(str(es))
      pass

  cursor.close()
  self.close_mysql()
```

The error for the above code after the fourth or so loop, it isn't always the same:
**Use cmd_query_iter for statements with multiple queries.**

You can assume that the update text above is 100% correct. Just to be certain, I also export my SQL statements to a text file which I then ran through my DB to ensure the correct results were achieved and they were. This is not a scalable solution however and I am automating this process so the ability to kick this off via cron is important.

Comment: I forgot to add. If I take the first 500 or so records, this works without an issue. Its only when it is a large dataset does this cause a problem with the executemany. Same thing if I loop through the data set and use the generic "execute". It works for the first 1000 or so records and then it starts to fail with the same error.

Comment: try with this  -> cur.executemany("UPDATE db_table SET column_1 = %s WHERE column_2 = %s ",[("item_1" , "TEST"),("item_2" , "TEST2"),("item_1" , "TEST3"),("item_2" , "TEST4")])

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar - I tried your solution with similar results as above.

Some updates: I have tried a few more things. I have broken my UPDATES into batches, and those failed as above. As the code stands right now, it loops through my data set, grabs 1000 records at a time, loops through those records and creates an update string. This is then used with a multi=true iterable cursor.execute. This works for about 4k records, and then I am given an error saying "Use cmd_query_iter for making statements with multiple queries" I have added this code block above.